# Google Sheets doc incorrect?

Tags: google-sheets

Is this an error in the documentation, or my code?

```
function myFunction() {
  var searchTerm="achievement";
  var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main");
  var cp=main.copy(searchTerm+"_" + main.getName());

  for(n=0;n<cp[0].length;++n){
    var cell = cp[0][n] ; // 0 is the index of the row. starting from 0
    if(!cell.indexOf(searchTerm)>-1)
    {
      cp.deleteColumn(n);
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot find function copy in object Sheet
```

Yet the docs seem to indicate the copy function exists: [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copy(String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code is in here:

```
  var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main");
```

If you were going to use the Spreadsheet.copy(..), you would copy SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(). In more common terms, it would actually copy the 'Workbook', all sheets included. What main contains is a specific Sheet, that is a single Sheet object within the Spreadsheet collection of Sheets.

It's the Google non-standard terms where things get convoluted.

If you wanted to copy a your Spreadsheet Sheet named Main to a new Sheet named search_term + ' ' + main.getName() you would use:

```
main.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(search_term + ' ' + main.getName());
```

This does the following:

1. Inserts a new Sheet with the new name with Search_Term
2. Copies the contents of main to your new Sheet.

From there you can select your new sheet by name and continue your code.

Comment: Thanks, that was a very thorough explanation